# Drake's AutoDiffXd query_object does not produce contact information

Tags: drake

Are there any differences in retrieving contact information between a `double` plant and an `AutoDiffXd` plant?

I created the same scene with both plants in my use case. The case with double reports the contact information with the context by the following code:

```
query_port_double = plant_double.get_geometry_query_input_port()
query_object_double = query_port_double.Eval(mutable_plant_context_double_list[0])
contact_info_port_double = plant_double.get_contact_results_output_port()
contact_results_double = contact_info_port_double.Eval(mutable_plant_context_double_list[0])
contact_results_double.num_point_pair_contacts()
```

However, when I do the same for AutoDiffXd case with the same procedures:

```
query_port_AD = plant_AD.get_geometry_query_input_port()
AD_query_object = query_port_AD.Eval(mutable_plant_contextAD_list[0])
contact_info_port_AD = plant_AD.get_contact_results_output_port()
contact_results_AD = contact_info_port_AD.Eval(mutable_plant_contextAD_list[0])
contact_results_AD.num_point_pair_contacts()
```

This reports 0 contacts. I checked current positions in the `plant_AD` with `plant_AD.GetPositions(mutable_plant_contextAD_list[0])`. It shows the same numerical values as in the `plant_double`.
Did I miss something when using the AutoDiffXd `query_object`?

Are the port connections wrong for the `plant_AD`? I did the following to create the AD version:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant = builder.AddSystem(MultibodyPlant(time_step=h))
parser = Parser(plant)
table_model_index = parser.AddModels(tablefile)[0]
box_model_index = parser.AddModels(boxfile)[0]
hand_model_index = parser.AddModels(handfile)[0]
table_top_frame = plant.GetFrameByName("table_top_center")
hand_frame = plant.GetFrameByName("panda_hand")
box_rame = plant.GetFrameByName("base_link_cracker")
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), table_top_frame, X_W_table)
plant.Finalize()

# convert into AD
builder_AD = DiagramBuilder_[AutoDiffXd]()
plant_AD = plant.ToScalarType[AutoDiffXd]()
connected_plantAD, connected_sceneGraphAD = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder_AD, plant_AD)
```

Another general question: how do I supply gradients to the solver when enforcing the constraints by functions inside which `plant` methods and also `geometry_query_input_port` are called. Does Drake do it internally? Can I provide the sparsity structure of the gradients? It would be nice if there is such a tutorial or example to poke around.

Thanks in advance! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for ComputePairPointPenetration()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#af3b16adde799eb804619dc86f3703f4f), you'll note that it has explicitly declared that contact isn't generally supported. You *can* get contact between spheres and some of the primitives. (I am mildly confused that your code doesn't throw....)

The most acute reason for this is that the underlying computations being used to compute point-pair contact aren't compatible with autodiff; essentially we can't guarantee that you get gradients, so we've chosen not to lie about it.

The support for AutoDiff is nominal -- it means if you have a Diagram with a `SceneGraph` in it and you want to convert the whole Diagram to AutoDiff for some purpose, the `SceneGraph` won't stop you. But it does mean you have a more limited set of operations you can do on the AutoDiff Diagram than you could on the double variant.

For constraints/costs you might consider simply using the signed distance in a `double`-valued Diagram. The signed distance *comes* with a gradient value. That is frequently used in minimum distance constraints and the like.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Then my question is: how is this `pydrake.geometry.SignedDistancePair_[AutoDiffXd] ` used then? I was trying to used Drake's scenegraph to compute sdf between points (or geometry Ids) and gradients. is there a work flow for this purpose?

Comment: I was poking around to get the gradient from Drake's signed distance. Could not find it. I was using `.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(GeomId_A, GeomId_B)`. Were you referring to this? Cheers!

Comment: I think I found it: `pydrake.geometry.SignedDistanceToPoint`. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You've basically got it. I guess the most important question is what gradient are you hoping to get. You can get the spatial gradient of distance using a `double`-valued query. If you want the derivatives w.r.t. to anything else, then, yes, you'll use AutoDiffXd and SignedDistanceToPoint.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! For my case, it is the latter. I need gradients w.r.t all decision variables. Cheers